# How to reduce the amount of Thunk code in the reudx-toolkit?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

There is a huge amount of thanks on the project, because this is the api backend. The question is how do I better group these thanks? I thought for a long time, but apart from the try catch block, I didn't come up with any more ideas to throw everything thanks. Below are just them and this is only 1\4 part of them...

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you're trying to achieve. Do you want to 1) group thunks or 2) reduce the amount of code in redux-toolkit (as in "inside the library itself") or 3) reduce the amount of code of thunks in your own project?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the thunks for normal data fetching, it might be interesting for you to look into [RTK Query](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/overview), which is also a part of Redux Toolkit and does all the thunks, reducers etc. for you - it just creates hooks for you that you can use in your application.

You can look at the [corresponding chapter in the Redux documentation](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-7-rtk-query-basics)